# Evaluating integral by cauchy formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $\int \frac{z^2 dz}{z^2+4}$ where C is the square with vertices at $2,-2,2+4i,-2+4i$ i used Cauchy integration formula,and i wrote the integrand as $ \frac{z/2}{z-2i}+\frac{z/2}{z+2i}$ i got $0$. Is my answer correct?

Comment: It should be $-2\pi$. The second integral is zero, while you get the value of the first via Cauchy's formula. Just plug in $2i$ (the only singularity inside the rectangle) and multiply the result by $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have poles at $2i$ and $-2i$.  Only one of those is inside your contour.

Cauchy integral formula:

$\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)} dz = 2\pi i f(a)$

Can you get your function into the form $f(z) / (z-2i)$?